# How can I disabled horizontal scrolling with a UIScrollView on page 2 of 3?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I have a horizontal `UIScrollView` with paging enabled containing 3 view controllers. The middle view contains touch handling that sometimes gets interpreted as scrolling and runs the user experience. I have navigation buttons for moving to page 1 and 3 but want to preserve the scrolling abilities when in page 1 and 3 since they don't have multitouch/complex touch behaviors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by implement the delegate method `func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView)`

here are some example code in Swift:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    if scrollView.contentOffset.x == view.frame.width {
        scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false
    } else {
        scrollView.isScrollEnabled = true
    }
}
```